# How to give style to iframed page content using parent pages css?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, xhtml, iframe

How to style iframed page's content using parent pages css ? I don't have access of iframed page?

i made thisfor example - http://jsbin.com/uxobe

how to style differently HTML of the page which i'm using in iframe?

Is therey a way to style like this through css or js+css ?

```
http://siteurl { background:red}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have no kind of access to the IFrame, neither from server side nor through JS because of cross domain issues: Not at all, I'm afraid.

If you can get hold of it through JS, you could sneak in own stylesheets one way or another, either by directly accessing and changing the styles (clean) or writing a `<style>` tag (not w3c valid).

Comment: In that case, cross domain security applies and you have no chance of styling the content. YOu would have to proxy the content through your own server to get access to it.

Comment: how can u please guide how can i proxy the content?

Comment: Ooh, that's a really long story with dozens of pitfalls, is not possible or too hard in many cases, is generally rarely a good idea and I am going home now :) Why not open another question about it.

Answer (score -2):

I was able to accomplish styling an object in the iframe src file by putting javascript in that file which looked for a query string value and did the styling (or not) based on the presence (or absence) of the query string.
This approach requires having control over the iframe target file, and worked well for me. I am trying to display a scaled down version of my own website in an iframe appearing in another one of my sites.