# Apply css style to iframe page before it loads

Tags: javascript, css, iframe

I have a page that loads an iFrame. I would like to apply a style to the iframe from the top page.

Following code works. But it applies on frame refresh. How can I make it apply before the iframe loads. Because for a second the item I'm setting display to none shows then goes away.

I tried window.onload which did not work at all. The onload event gets called but the style does not set.

No I can not put the style inside the iFrame page directly. It's out of my control.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function onFrameRefreshed() {
        frames['testIframe'].document.getElementById("bannerDiv").style.display="none";
    }
</script>

<div>
    <iframe name="testIframe" ID="testIframe" src="https://someframepage.mycompany.com" width="100%"
        height="1000px" onload="onFrameRefreshed()" frameborder="0">No iframe support </iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Answered here: [Using CSS to affect div style inside iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/583753/using-css-to-affect-div-style-inside-iframe)

Comment: The links says its not possible. My question is not about it being possible or not. I know it's possible because I'm doing it. Code included. My question is if I can run the JS code on some other event that manipulates the page before the browser renders it. Some kind of before onload event.