# Colorbox show specific element of another page

Tags: jquery, iframe, colorbox

I'm wondering if this is somehow possible, though it is not allowed to manipulate content from another domain via `Javascript` through an `iframe`.

I'm wanting to use `Colorbox` to load a specific element from another page. So, if on the other website, there is a container `div#shell`, I want the `Colorbox` to show me only the content within `div#shell`.

This content is on another domain, so, I'm not sure if this is possible. I think I'll be limited to screenshots...

Answer (score 3):

No for security reasons.

Take a look @http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533028.aspx

[Using CSS to affect div style inside iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/583753/using-css-to-affect-div-style-inside-iframe)

[CSS override body style for content in iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6494721/css-overide-body-style-for-content-in-iframe)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of an iframe, you could use jQuery ajax to pull the page into a variable and find the appropriate section by parsing the HTML.

Comment: Agreed, and remember that the jQuery AJAX calls support pulling only part of the content of the target, as in `$('#result').load('ajax/test.html #container');` which would acquire only the element with ID of container.