# Set CSS for iframe from third party site

Tags: css, iframe

I am trying to style the [snapwidget instagram feed](http://snapwidget.com/#getstarted), I want to make the border white.  This is not a setting of the widget so I tried adding css.  It seems that my css is not being detected since the content is in an iframe.  Is there a way to force my css on the iframe content?

Comment: See this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/217776/how-to-apply-css-to-iframe

Comment: you can only do that, if the iframe is from the same domain.

Comment: Any updates on this question? I don't see any accepted answers..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It won't work unless the iframe is on the same domain due to same origin policy. http://javascript.info/tutorial/same-origin-security-policy

Check out [Using CSS to affect div style inside iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/583753/using-css-to-affect-div-style-inside-iframe) for an explanation