# Accessing and printing HTML source code using PHP or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to access and then print (or just be able to use) the source code of any website using PHP. I am not very experienced and am now thinking I might need to use JS to accomplish this. So far, the code below accesses the source code of a web page and displays the web page... What I want it to do instead is display the source code. Essentially, and most importantly, I want to be able to store the source code in some sort of variable so I can use it later. And eventually read it line-by-line - but this can be tackled later.

```
$url = 'http://www.google.com';
function get_data($url) 
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 5;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}
echo get_data($url); //print and echo do the same thing in this scenario.
```

Comment: You can use `document.body.innerHTML`, pretty simple, isn't it?

Comment: Can you explain this further? Maybe give an example? @gdoron

Answer (score 2):

<strike>Consider using [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) instead of `curl`.</strike>  You can then display the code on your page by replacing every opening bracket (<) with `&lt;` and then outputting it to the page.

```
<?php
$code = file_get_contents('http://www.google.com');
$code = str_replace('<', '&lt;', $code);
echo $code;
?>
```

**Edit:**
Looks like curl is actually faster than FGC, so ignore that suggestion.  The rest of my post still stands.  :)

Comment: Set the content-type as plain-text?

Comment: +1 I did not know `cURL` was faster than `file_get_contents` for remote connections.

Comment: @SenorAmor It prints out 'Resource id #1' and that's it!

Answer (score 1):

You should try to print the result between `<pre></pre>` tags;

```
echo '<pre>' . get_data($url) . '</pre>';
```

Comment: This didn't seem to work. It only changed some of the fonts and formatting of the displayed web page.

Comment: maybe `echo '<pre>'; print_r(get_data($url)); echo '<pre>';`

Answer (score 1):

I rewrote your function. The function can return the source with lines or without lines.

```
<?php 
function get_data($url, $Addlines = false){
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
    $content = curl_exec($ch);
    $content = htmlspecialchars($content); // Prevents the browser to parse the html

    curl_close($ch);

    if ($Addlines == true){
        $content = explode("\n", $content);
        $Count = 0;
        foreach ($content as $Line){
            $lines = $lines .= 'Line '.$Count.': '.$Line.'<br />';
            $Count++;
        }
        return $lines;
    } else {
        $content = nl2br($content);
        return $content;
    }
}


echo get_data('https://www.google.com/', true); // Source code with lines
echo get_data('https://www.google.com/'); // Source code without lines
?>
```

Hope it gets you on your way.

Answer (score 0):

Add a header Content-Type: text/plain

```
header("Content-Type: plain/text");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [htmlspecialchars()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) in php to print the source code.

In your code, use

`return htmlspecialchars($data);`

instead of

`return $data;`