# Exists any way to set "width=100%" of a DIV contained in a iframe?

Tags: html, css, facebook, wordpress

I'm using [Facebook Comments](https://wordpress.org/plugins/facebook-comments-plugin/) plugin in a Wordpress site, recently and apparently Facebook made some changes and now the plugin looks bad. I tried to change the width of `div#feedback_` with jQuery:

```
j('[class^="feedback_"]').css('width', '100%' );
```

without luck. This is part of the HTML code where problem is

```
<div id="feedback_0AedXk4SLwjqTpZaj" style="width: 100px;">
    <div id="u_0_0" class="fbFeedbackContent">
        ... some other useless for this post HTML here
    </div>
</div>
```

The string "0AedXk4SLwjqTpZaj" after `feedback_` is generated dynamically trough WP, any help or advice?

**EDIT**

Why I getting downvotes?

Comment: `feedback_...` is class or id? isn't it an id? so the jQuery code does not work.

Comment: I'm guessing the downvotes are for not posting your HTML markup within your post, linking to an external site, (which will be useless as an example once you have fixed the problem) and/or making us search through your entire site code to find the issue.

Comment: @DrydenLong ok, sorry for that one, I'll write the HTML code here

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using CSS to affect div style inside iframe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/583753/using-css-to-affect-div-style-inside-iframe)

Comment: @KingKing I changed to id and still not working

Comment: _“and now the plugin looks bad”_ – can you be a bit more specific, perhaps?

Comment: @CBroe well I mean before the DIV width was 100% now it's 100px and that's what I mean when I said "and now the plugin looks bad"