# access an element through CSS Path from outside of iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

i want to access a dom element through CSS Path inside the iframe. following is the direct CSS Path:

```
var dompath = "html body div div div div div div div ul li a:contains('Parks')";

$(dompath).click();
```

the above line is working fine if i am opening the page without iframe.

I want to open the same page inside the iframe and want to trigger click on the above element from outside the iframe. i have tried in this way, but its not working.

```
            $('#scaled_frame').contents().(domPath).click();
```

how can i perform the click action from outside.

Best Regards,

Comment: Do you have access to the files inside of the iframe?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/583753/using-css-to-affect-div-style-inside-iframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: `$('#scaled_frame').contents().find(domPath).click();`

Comment: i just want to trigger or simulate the click event onto that element. i dont need the event handler.

Comment: @user2674341, Try this: `$('#scaled_frame').contents().find(domPath).click();`

Comment: @user2674341 no problem, you can check my answer as the correct one and vote up maybe?