# How to customize the dropdown menu of Google translate plugin in css?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I can't figure out that how I can change the background of the dropdrown menu of the google translate plugin

**HTML**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function googleTranslateElementInit() {
            new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en', includedLanguages: 'en,tl', layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE, autoDisplay: false}, 'google_translate_element');
        }
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
```

**CSS**

```
.goog-te-menu2 { 
    background-color: #000000 !important; 
    text-decoration: none; 
    border: 1px solid #f00 !important; 
    overflow: hidden; 
    padding: 4px;
}
```

and nothing's happen at all anyone can help me how to style this dropdown menu

Comment: Do you have a link perhaps?

Comment: it's just on the localhost

Comment: Can you make a fiddle?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/c79bj68b/ here's the fiddle

Comment: The menu that is being loaded is loaded in an iframe, which you can't affect with CSS. [According to this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/583753/using-css-to-affect-div-style-inside-iframe), you can edit it with javascript, but [according to this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/217776/how-to-apply-css-to-iframe?rq=1), you need access to edit the page, or the page needs to allow direct access through Access-Control-Origin to use php's file_get_contents. It's messy.