# Overwrite Shopify Embed Buy Button iframe styling

Tags: css, button, embed, shopify, overwrite

Basically my question is as exactly as the title suggest.

I want to override the css styling of Shopify's embedded buy button iframe, but I am not sure how.

I as assuming this will be extremely tricky, if not impossible? As I have tried many things and it seems that all of my css affecting the Shopify's embedded button is ignored.

I have tried adding !important to styling and this doesn't seem to do anything either.

Is there a way to add styling after the iframe has loaded in browser? I am guessing that this is the last thing that loads, hence why my css is being ignored/overwritten.

Any help would be great.

PS. I do not have a website link to provide as it is for a client and a signed NDA has legally prevented me from uploading the site, even in a test environment.

Thanks,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to apply CSS to iframe?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/217776/how-to-apply-css-to-iframe)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using CSS to affect div style inside iframe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/583753/using-css-to-affect-div-style-inside-iframe)

Comment: Did you post this as a job on PPH? I referred the chap to stack overflow...

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the only supported customizations are the ones listed [here](https://help.shopify.com/manual/sell-online/buy-button/edit-delete). There's no way to override styles within an iframe on another domain. However, we've built the [JS Buy SDK](http://shopify.github.io/js-buy-sdk/) to support greater customization, though it would require more intensive development. That said, there are some [examples](http://shopify.github.io/js-buy-sdk/examples/) you could use to get started.