# How to target image inside iframe

Tags: css, iframe

How can I target image inside iframe with CSS?

This doesn't work

```
iframe img {
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
}
```

[image]

Comment: That's not possible with CSS only, check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/583753/using-css-to-affect-div-style-inside-iframe

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try jquery for this

```
$('iframe').contents().find('img').css({width: '100%', 'height': '100%'});
```

wrap this in jQuery load callback if iframe loads later after the page loaded

```
$('iframe').load(function() {
    $(this).contents().find('img').css({width: '100%', 'height': '100%'});
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
document.querySelector('iframe[name="content2"]').contentWindow.addEventListener('load',function(e){e.target.body.style.textAlign='center'},false)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem but the answer is same that you can't access things in `<iframe>` neither with css nor with jquery.

If you have access to the page you are using in `<iframe>` go and write css on that page then it will be automatically work in `<iframe>`. But you cant change anything in `<iframe>` with external code.

Answer (score 0):

try this under the same domain. otherwise it throws cross origin error.

Update with On load jQuery function.

```
$('iframe').on("load", function () {

    $(this).contents().find('img').css({width: '100%', 'height': '100%'});

});
```