# How to make content of Google form wider?

Tags: css, iframe, google-forms

Content of google form is by default 640px wide  - which is set in class ".freebirdFormviewerViewCenteredContent", I need to make this wider. I´m embeding it on website with iframe and I can´t find solution how to add "width" css to make it work. It´s possible?

Answer (score 5):

You can't style an iframe with CSS, there are two ways to solve the problem though:

- Use javascript to style it: take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/583753/using-css-to-affect-div-style-inside-iframe)
- Don't use an iframe: use [this tutorial](https://morningstudio.com.au/blog/2013/06/how-to-style-google-forms/) to style the whole form without using an iframe

Answer (score 0):

What I did to change the width of the form was change the width within the embedded code within the iframe.

Comment: How is it not an attempt to answer the question? I stated what I did to solve the same issue as asked.

Comment: If you provide your code (and perhaps also a couple of screenies), I would not be surprised to see upvotes).

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, there is no way to do that and I have looked everywhere. Currently, there isn't an option to make the Google Form wider.

Check out this link on google forum:
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/FaGfvxnm51U