# Hide div using class in iframe window using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I have `iframe` html tag it has an `id="FrameDisplay"` property and I display other site content in this frame and want to hide the div in frame window, if it is possible, in frame content has class `.top-float` and i want to hide it.

```
<div class="row" id="FrameDisplay"> <iframe id="Iframe" src="#" frameborder="0"></iframe> </div>
```

In my frame window other site display so it possible to hide div using class in JavaScript.

Comment: Hopefully the following answer will help you

 [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/251420/invoking-javascript-code-in-an-iframe-from-the-parent-page][]

Comment: <div class="row" id="FrameDisplay">
                    <iframe id="Iframe" src="#"  frameborder="0"></iframe>
                 </div>     and in iframe i load other site content and want to hide div on other domain site that load in iframe.

Comment: If you are displaying third party website content in your IFrame, this is not possible due to cross-origin policy.

Comment: dear,  Nuwan.Niroshana  there is any way to hide div for third party in my i frame?

Comment: Also relevant: [Using CSS to affect div style inside iframe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/583753/using-css-to-affect-div-style-inside-iframe)