# Can I force custom base value for absolute font-size (medium, x-large) in CSS?

Tags: css, font-size, keyword, absolute

Suppose I have no choice but to use absolute font-size value, e.g. `font-size: x-large;`. According to many articles, the exact font size of such an element depends on user's preferences. My question (maybe silly) is: can I force some custom value instead of user's preferences as a base?

E.g. I have a given HTML document with absolute-size values, and I want to render it inside of an iframe (under same domain) with some configurable value as a font base. So that elements with font-size "x-large", "medium", "small", etc. change their real font size according to this base value. It might be useful e.g. just to demonstrate how these font values work. Can I achieve this at all? And how? Maybe there's a specific property in window object like "window.fontSizePreference" - who knows...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If an `absolute` value has already been declared, and you want to simply replace it using a `length` value, you have a few options.

## Possible Solutions

Override the **CSS** by being more [specific](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity). If your code is declaring the value using:

```
div.xlarge {
  font-size: x-large;
}
```

You could add another CSS `selector` to target that `div`, and CSS would use the more specific of the two values. For example, you could add `body` or the parent container:

```
body div.xlarge {
  font-size: 12px; /* This would overwrite the x-large value above */
}
div div.xlarge {
  font-size: 12px /* So would this */
}
.parentclass div.xlarge {
  font-size: 12px; /* And this */
}
```

For the sake of the example, I'm using a `div` with a parent `div` and a parent with the class name of `.parentclass`. You could also use `span`, `p`, `li`, `ul`, `a`, etc.

> **Note:** Learn more about [Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) from MDN.

---

You could also add styling inline to the desired target. For example, if your **HTML** is:

```
<div class="xlarge">My Text</div>
```

You could add inline styling like so and it would override the `font-size` CSS declared value:

```
<div class="xlarge" style="font-size: 12px;">My Text</div>
```

---

The last thing I'd recommend, is using the `!important` tag to override **CSS** values you couldn't otherwise target using the above methods. Assuming there is no other `!important` declarations, the last `!important` will force the **CSS** value.

```
div.xlarge {
  font-size: 12px !important; /* Will override more specific CSS & Inline CSS */
  font-size: x-large; /* Would be ignored */
```

> **Note:** Learn about using `!important` from [CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/).

---

## IFrames

None of these solutions will work with just **CSS** if you are trying to edit an `iframe`, unless you have control of the `iframe` content. For editing `iframe` **CSS**, just do a quick search on Stack Overflow and there are a [number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217776/how-to-apply-css-to-iframe) of [solutions.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/583753/using-css-to-affect-div-style-inside-iframe)

Comment: Thank you for the verbose answer, but that's not it.

First, I've noticed that _I have no choice but to use absolute font-size value, e.g. font-size: x-large_. I know about selectors specificity, "!important" rule and cross-domain iframes. If I could use font-size in pixels, this question wouldn't arise. So can I change one basic value to affect all such font sizes, or the only option is what you described - to replace each and every font-size statement? Maybe there's a specific property in window object like "window.fontSizePreference" - who knows...

Comment: Second, you replaced font-sizes with static "12px", while "x-large" may lead to different real values depending  user's preferences and webkit **font boosting** on mobile devices. So how do I get real font size (in pixels) in such case?

Comment: @AlexeyGrinko So you are trying to change the user's default font that is set by the browser, and used to calculate the `absolute` value for fonts? If so, the simple answer is no, that's not possible. There is a good reason that browsers have default font sizes, and you won't be able to access that through the DOM.