# Override iframe fixed size iz shortcode for wordpress plugin

Tags: wordpress, css, iframe, css-transitions

I am working with wordpress plugin for fb feed.  It gives a short code where you can set width and height. But only in pixels. Is there a chance to set it in % (width and height 100%)?

Here is a code:

```
[efb_likebox fanpage_url="SPIBiH" box_width="336" box_height="487" locale="en_US" responsive="1" show_faces="1" show_stream="1" hide_cover="0" small_header="0" hide_cta="0" animate_effect="fadeIn" ]
```

This creates HTML with iframe. I don't know how to override this sizes in css.

Answer (score 1):

This has been answered here: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/583753/using-css-to-affect-div-style-inside-iframe`

You can't target the iframe with CSS oridinarily, but you can add some javascript that will add classes to your iframe that can be targeted.