# How to edit iframe CSS in tidio chat

Tags: javascript, html, css

everybody,

I am using wordpress to create an eCommerce website and install plugin for tidio chat. 
I would like to adjust the position (bottom) for tidio chat,currently is 0px but i found that it is using iframe and i cannot change it by add custom css.

```
<iframe title="Tidio Chat" id="tidio-chat-iframe" style="display: block; border: none; position: fixed; width: 112px; height: 140px; opacity: 1; left: auto; right: 0px; bottom: 0px; top: auto; background: none transparent; margin: 0px; max-height: 100vh; max-width: 100vw; transform: translateY(0px); transition: none 0s ease 0s; visibility: visible; z-index: 999999999 !important;"></iframe>
```

What is the code to add in javascript, i try many times to add in code but still fail, anyone can help me about this issue? 
Thank you so much.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using CSS to affect div style inside iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/583753/using-css-to-affect-div-style-inside-iframe)

Comment: thanks for your feedback, i will go check and study

Answer (score 3):

It's possible to move the whole iframe itself, but this can only work for the desktop version of the widget (moving the mobile one will make it exceed the screen boundaries).

Try using this style code in the header of the site:

```
<style>
#tidio-chat iframe { bottom: 3.5em !important; }
@media only screen and (max-width: 980px) {
    #tidio-chat iframe { bottom: 0px !important; }
}
</style>
```

The first line is responsible for moving the widget, so you can play around with the values to position the chat as desired. The second and third line are responsible for excluding the mobile widget from being moved, so I'd recommend leaving them unchanged.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Martin Iwaszko, Thank you for your support and helping.

Answer (score 1):

To apply this to many themes in WordPress, you will need to have the css in the footer. This can be done with the get_footer hook.

1. Create a new footer.css file in your child theme. I put it in assets/css/footer.css. Add the css:

   #tidio-chat iframe { bottom: 0em !important; }
   @media only screen and (max-width: 980px) {
   #tidio-chat iframe { bottom: -1em !important; }
   }
2. In your child theme's functions.php file, add the following function:

   function childtheme_add_footer_styles() {
   wp_enqueue_style( 'your-style-id', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/footer.css' );
   };
   add_action( 'get_footer', 'childtheme_add_footer_styles' );

This will add the css in the footer, which will apply it to the tidio chat icon. When loading the css in the themes style.css, it loads in the header and does not apply it.