# How to get only one scrollbar bar when putting div inside a form tag

Tags: html, forms, iframe, scrollbar

I am creating a asp page which contains form tag.Inside it, it contains a div.
Inside div it contains a iframe. When the height of div is defined to greater px i.e 1500px.I get two scroll bar on right of the page. How to show only one Scroll bar?

I have tried all the possible solution given in stactoverflow.

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

        <div style="height: 1500px;" >
            <iframe id="mainFrame" name="mainFrame" scrolling="auto" height="100%" width="100%" frameborder="0" src="../Front.aspx" onload="ParentScrollTop();"></iframe>
         </div>

       <script type="text/javascript">
           function ParentScrollTop() {
              $("html,body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 100);
          }
       </script>



    </form>
</body>
```

i expect a page with only one scrollbar no matter what height of div is defined.

Comment: Can you also share the code for `ParentScrollTop()`?

Comment: Mr. Tshimkus i have shared the code for ParentScrollTop().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify in `CSS` by putting `overflow` property.

> overflow-x (Horizontal)
>
> overflow-y (Vertical)

To hide vertical scroll bar

```
   .mainFrame{
    
      width:1500px; // Element Width
      height:500px; // Element Height
      overflow-y: hidden;
    
    }
```

To hide horizontal scroll bar

```
    .mainFrame{
    
      width:1500px; // Element Width
      height:500px; // Element Height
      overflow-x: hidden;
    
    }
```

Comment: Sorry this css property did not hide the scroll bars.neither vertical nor horizontal

Comment: Inner scroll bar is appearing due to height of div not from iframe. So i think setting css property to iframe doesnot seems to be a solution.

Comment: Apply style to the frame elements

Comment: Can you please elaborate more

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/583753/using-css-to-affect-div-style-inside-iframe

Comment: When i applied that css property to the div it worked fine. Thank you Mr. Banujan Balendrakumar

Comment: But it does not work for Internet Explorer browser.How to get it work for internet browser also??

Comment: `IE` is really damn browser, Anyways you need to add this line `-ms-overflow-y:hidden` to enable that property in `IE` (It's Depends on IE versions). And also make sure that you have added `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" /> ` inside your `<head> </head>` tags.

Comment: msg:- "ms-overflow-y:hidden is not a known Css property name " is displayed when i put that css