# How to make iframe in top of navbar in css?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have an iframe that will popup when I click the button. But the navbar will be on top of it unless I scroll down.

This is my practice site:

http://test1.video-power.net/products/videopower-red/

this is the error

[image]

but when I scroll down, it's all correct. It only occurs when I'm on the highest scroll

This is when I scroll down and it's okay.

[image]

I've tried to add this but it still not working.

```
.main-container {
    margin-top:50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give your header (CSS class fusion-header-wrapper) a z-index of 10 or something that would hold your header under your iframe, and set the 'top' property of the main-container class inside your iframe to pull it a little down.

```
.fusion-header-wrapper { z-index: 10; } /* goes into your actual page */
.main-container { top: 50px;  } /* goes into your iframe */
```

Comment: by the way, I can't edit the iframe. 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/583767/13054808