# Trying to add css styling to iframe with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, iframe

Trying this on Wordpress:

Inside my `iframe` I have a `._2p3a` class I want to change its width to `._2p3a {width: 100% !important;}`.

With CSS its not possible to access that class so I am trying with JavaScript:

MY JS CODE:

```
function hello() {
   let myiFrame = document.getElementById("iframe-css");
   let doc = myiFrame.contentDocument;
   doc.body.innerHTML = doc.body.innerHTML + '<style>._2p3a{width: 100% !important;}</style>';
}
```

`//the iframe id > "iframe-css"`

code Source: https://redstapler.co/how-to-apply-css-to-iframe/

The error:

```
land_page.js?ver=1.0:4 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'body' of null
    at hello (land_page.js?ver=1.0:4)
    at HTMLIFrameElement.onload ((index):539)
```

underlined code:

```
.body.innerHTML = doc.body.innerHTML + '<style>._2p3a{width: 100% !important;}</style>';
```

Tried: [Using CSS to affect div style inside iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/583753/using-css-to-affect-div-style-inside-iframe)
(got errors with all examples "None worked").

I am running this function with `onload="hello(this)"` on my iframe.

Any other suggestions how I can edit that class to make its width 100%??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decided to use a different plugin since using the facebook iframe was causing some trouble. With this new plugin everything is working fine so yea.

Thanks to anyone who put effort to answering, I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

please try bellow code ... I hope you get result:

```
let myiFrame = document.getElementById("iframe-css").contentWindow;
let doc = myiFrame.document;
doc.body.innerHTML = doc.body.innerHTML + '<style>._2p3a{width: 100% !important;}</style>';
```

Comment: Got the following error """land_page.js?ver=1.0:7 Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
    at hello (http://localhost/landing_page/wp-content/themes/betheme-child/land_page.js?ver=1.0:7:24)
    at HTMLIFrameElement.onload (http://localhost/landing_page/:539:972)""" I think because its a facebook iframe the DOM is blocking my javascript code request

Comment: yes its block because its not in your origin but if both of theme (iframe and parrent) in same domain or address it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a `<style>` element isn't the best way to do this. However, even if it was, you should try to avoid adding elements via `innerHTML`. It is better to use `Document.createElement` (`document` is an instance of `Document`) and `Element.appendChild` (all elements are instances of the `Element` class).

The best way to do this is by directly modifying the style of the elements in the class.

```js
function hello() {
  let myiFrame = document.getElementById("iframe-css");
  let doc = myiFrame.contentDocument ?? myiFrame.contentWindow?.document ?? new Document();
  let elements = doc.getElementsByClassName("2p3a");
  for(let i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i) {
    elements[i].style.width = "100%";
  }
}
```

Also, the `onload` attribute sometimes doesn't work on an iFrame. You may have to use the DOM like this:

```js
document.getElementById("iframe-css").onload = hello;
```

On a side note, you should generally stick to 2 or 4 spaces of indentation in JavaScript, but you chose 3.

Comment: Got the following error from this """land_page.js?ver=1.0:9 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'contentDocument' of null
    at hello (land_page.js?ver=1.0:9)
    at land_page.js?ver=1.0:16"""

Comment: @RandomCoder Make sure your id is correct. If it is, make sure that `hello` is getting run AFTER the iframe is loaded. Keep in mind that you can only access the iframe's onload AFTER the DOM has been loaded. Maybe this code will fix your issue:

`window.onload = () => { document.getElementById("iframe-css").onload = hello; };`

If that doesn't fix your issue, try this:

`window.onload = hello;`

If that STILL doesn't fix your issue, then I'm not sure what to tell you other than to try jQuery's `$(document).ready` method.