# Style vimeo play-bar and play button

Tags: javascript, html, css, vimeo-player

How can I style(change: bg-color, border-radius etc..)the play-bar and play-button in the vp-controls of a vimeo video. My vimeo is embadded with vimeo-player in an iframe.
I would like to do it with js/html/css?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use userstyles for this... At the moment, I can't think of anything other than using either userstyles or an immense amount of javascript code in an iframe to change css (think finding the html code in the iframe, the css in that html, then overwriting the css), etc.

Would you be able to give me a link to your website for me?

Comment: Yes, that what i want to overwrite the css but i dont manage i tried from my css files but the iframe not recognize it, how do i apply the styleguides?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/583753/using-css-to-affect-div-style-inside-iframe should help. It requires JavaScript to work. Wait for the IFrame to load, and add your `<link>` inside of it. I also have a library that could work with this.