# Click on button underneath a container that covers it

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make it so that the review button underneath the chat overlay container can be clicked when the chat overlay container is on top. The size of the chat overlay container can't be changed. I have tried with stacking options `z-index`. I thought about the CSS option `pointer-events` but the x in the top right and the circle chat button needs to remain clickable. Any help is much appreciated thanks.

The following is an image in inspector with the chat overlay container highlighted.

[image: inspect with chat overlay container selected]

The following is simplified version of how the html is structured for the chat overlay and the card container.

```html
<div class="card">
   <p class="title">example.com</p>
   <button class="review">Review</button>
</div>

<div class="overlay">
   <div class=help-text>
      <button class="dismiss-help">X</button>
      <p>Got any questions....</p>
   </div>
   <span class="overlay-launcher">
     <button class="launcher-button">Circle</button>
   </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would continue exploring the use of `pointer-events`.

`pointer-events` is an inherited property, so if a value isn't explicitly set, it will inherit the computed value from it's parent.

Try `pointer-events: none` on the chat overlay, but `pointer-events: auto` on the children that should remain clickable. eg close button and toggle chat button (or one of their common ancestors).

```js
// Not required. Only here to demonstrate click events
document
.querySelectorAll('button')
.forEach(button => 
  {
  button.addEventListener('click', (e) => 
    {
    console.log(`clicked ${e.currentTarget.textContent.trim()}`)
    })
  })
```

```css
.overlay {
  background     : rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.5);
  position       : absolute;
  top            : 0;
  pointer-events : none;
  outline        : 1px solid blue;
  }
.overlay button {
  pointer-events : auto;
  }
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <p class="title">example.com</p>
  <button class="review">Review</button>
</div>

<div class="overlay">
  <div class=help-text>
    <button>X</button>
    <p>Got any questions....</p>
  </div>
  <span class="overlay-launcher">
     <button class="launcher-button">Circle</button>
   </span>
</div>
```

Comment: I follow what you suggest and I can leave only the the X and chat launcher clickable. But the area underneath is still unclickable

Comment: What is the area underneath? The Review button?

Comment: It is a card container that contains a button

Comment: Can you click on the review button in the above example?

Comment: It works in your example. But that is because your overlay content upon chrome inspect in blue does not overlap the review button. Only the padding which is green in chrome inspect overlaps the review button.

Comment: I don't think that is correct. Padding on `.overlay` has no impact.

Comment: Now there is no padding and you can still click every button.

Comment: Ok so I eventually found the parent div in which doing `pointer-events:none` works and I can click the review button on overlap. But the overlay and its associated html is loaded in with an `<iframe>` which has issues inheriting/accessing styles. Can't seem to override it to make just the buttons clickable.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/583753/using-css-to-affect-div-style-inside-iframe

Answer (score -1):

**z-index and position:relative** help the ".help-text",".launcher-button" classes to **stay on top of other contents**.

```css
.overlay{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  align-items:end;
  width:fit-content;
  
}
.help-text{
  background:white;
  width:fit-content;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  align-items:end;
  z-index:1;
  position:relative;
  /*    z-index and position:relative help .help-text to stay on top of other contents  */
}

.help-text>p{
  font-family:sans-serif;
}
.dismiss-help{
  background-color:transparent;
  border:none;
}

.launcher-button{
  width:3rem;
  aspect-ratio:1;
  border-radius:50%;
  border:none;
  background-image:linear-gradient(to left,rgba(0,100,180,1) 30%,rgba(0,0,255,1));
  margin-top:1rem;
  z-index:1; 
  position:relative;
/*    z-index and position:relative help launcher button to stay on top of other contents  */
}

#samplebtn{
  position:absolute;
  top:40%;
  left:90px;
  height:2rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="overlay">
   <div class=help-text>
      <button class="dismiss-help">X</button>
      <p>Got any questions....</p>
   </div>
   <span class="overlay-launcher">
     <button class="launcher-button">Circle</button>
   </span>
</div>
<button id="samplebtn">Review
</button>
```