# Where do I put the style tags?

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is a widget for a website, and I'm trying to figure out where am I supposed to put the style tags to edit any of the styles within the widget. I can get what I want with Chrome inspector tool, but I'm not sure where I need to add in the css. Thanks!

```
<script>
    var fm = "PHP";
    var to = "USD";
    var tz = "timezone";
    var sz = "1x1";
    var lg = "en";
    var st = "primary";
    var lr = "0";
    var rd = "0";
</script>
<script src="//currencyrate.today/converter"></script>
<div style="text-align:right">
    <a href="https://currencyrate.today">
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I went and checkout out the widget code and it doesn't appear you can do much with the JS snippet version - since it creates an iframe element. There are couple themes you can pick from using the site's generator tool. What are you trying to actually style?

Comment: Picked the wrong duplicate when closing. Here's the real one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/583753/using-css-to-affect-div-style-inside-iframe

Answer (score 1):

You cannot alter the contents of the widget with CSS or JS - this is for [security reasons](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy).

The widget is rendered inside an iframe, and as such it cannot be accessed from outside unless you were accessing from the same domain (and unless you happen to own the currencyrate.today website, you are accessing it from a different one)

Comment: Apologies (accidentally edited and overwrote another users comment asking how I knew they were using an iframe), answer here:

I opened the js source: currencyrate.today/converter - In there is code to embed an iframe