# Replace YouTube play pause button of iframe

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, iframe

Is there any way to change YouTube iframe play pause button using css?
I am using multiple iframes and i want to change that red play button.

I have tried

```css
.ytp-large-play-button{
  background: url(play.png);
}
```

But it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### In short, you can't.

Because:

You [have to use Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/583753/using-css-to-affect-div-style-inside-iframe) to change the style inside `<iframe>`.

To do this, you first get the DOM element

```js
let redPlayButton = document.getElementById('youtube-iframe').contentWindow.document.getElementsByClassName('ytp-large-play-button')[0];
```

and then make changes to it:

```js
redPlayButton.style.background = "https://something-here";
```

However, according to the [Same-origin policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098021/securityerror-blocked-a-frame-with-origin-from-accessing-a-cross-origin-frame), you can only do this to an `<iframe>` element which is coming from your own server.

> You can't access an `<iframe>` with different origin using JavaScript, it would be a huge security flaw if you could do it. For the [same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) **browsers block scripts trying to access a frame with a different origin.**